# make a custom navigation drawer using material design

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop

I am making an app with material design in Eclipse, and I am a beginner in material design. Let me explain my problem:

What I have done: [Android Getting Started with Material Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

[image]

And What I want:

[image]

Please guide me, don't know how it will be done.

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement. Please be specific.

Comment: Do you want navigation drawer on right?

Comment: yes navigation drawer in right and with extra buttons also, which you see in the 2nd picture(having list/map etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It will help...

Navigation Drawer with both left and right Menu

https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer

Answer (score 0):

To switch navigation drawer to right you just need to set the layout_gravity to end.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    />
```

Remove the Hamburger Icon from toolbar. Add a custom hamburger icon to right most in toolbar menu.xml.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_open_drawer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_hamburger_white_24dp"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="drawer"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Now in your OnOptionSelected method open Drawer on action_open_drawer button click.

```
if (id == R.id.action_open_drawer) {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }
```